# How to use find for nested object of objects in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have nested object of objects. Each document in collection looks like this:

```
{
   anything: "whatever",
   something: {
      // find inside of these document
      a: { getThis: "wow" },
      b: { getThis: "just wow" },
      c: { getThis: "another wow" }
   }
}
```

I would like to `find` in every `getThis` from each document in `something`.

---

For example I would like to find document which has `getThis: "wow"`.

I've tried to use something like wildcard with `*`:

```
{"something.*.getThis": "wow" }
```

I've also tried `$elemMatch` but [it seems it works only with `array`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/);

```
{ something: { $elemMatch: { getThis: "wow" } } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `$objectToArray`,

- `$addFields` to convert `something` to array in `somethingArr`
- `$match` condition `getThis` is `wow` or not
- `$project` to remove `somethingArr`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      somethingArr: { $objectToArray: "$something" }
    }
  },
  { $match: { "somethingArr.v.getThis": "wow" } },
  { $project: { somethingArr: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l-zGZ-Ua0ix)

---

**Second possible way**

- `$filter` input `something` as array, convert using `$objectToArray`
- filter will check condition `getThis` is equal to `wow` or not

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          [],
          {
            $filter: {
              input: { $objectToArray: "$something" },
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.v.getThis", "wow"] }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/28s-BgS8Clu)